# Reading TestNG annotation parameter value from Properties file

Tags: java, properties, testng

I am using TestNG. I need to read the value of `"invocationCount"` from the `Properties` file.
I tried below, but getting compilation errors. Can someone please help me on this?

```
public static final int TC=Integer.parseInt(p.getProperty("threadcount"));

@Test(threadPoolSize=10,invocationCount=TC)
public void someMethod { }
```

***Compilation error:*** The value for annotation attribute Test.invocationCount must be a constant expression

Comment: As it says, annotation values in Java must be constant expressions...

Comment: Then, is it not possible to read from Properties file?

Comment: Check in 5.15 of the documentation: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html - you can do something like `annotation.setInvocationCount(TC);`.

Comment: Can you pls elaborate?Where do I need to put the above statement?Inside the method?

Answer (score 2):

Srikanth, you would need to implement the IAnnotationTransformer that Testng exposes.  You can write code to read your properties file and set the invocation count of the current test being invoked in the implementation of transform method.  [This](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotationtransformers) gives an example.

Specify your implementation of Iannotationtransformer as a listener in your tests, either in your suite.xml or at your class level with @Listeners annotation as elaborated [here](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#listeners-testng-xml)